# MdapiDeployCommand No org configuration found for name

Tags: windows, salesforce, salesforce-cli

I am getting below error message when I try to validate salesforce deployment against target salesforce org.

```
{
    "status": 1,
    "name": "NoOrgFound",
    "message": "No org configuration found for name '00D18000000954Y!AQcAQEu9XXfRJP2hXd0lJX4Dp2CohWjDzXuvqrcNF'",
    "exitCode": 1,
    "commandName": "MdapiDeployCommand",
    "stack": "NoOrgFound: No org configuration found for name '00D18000000954Y!AQcAQEu9XXfRJP2hXd0lJX4Dp2CohWjDzXuvqrcNF'\n    at Function.create (C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\node_modules\\@salesforce\\core\\lib\\sfdxError.js:141:16)\n    at AuthInfo.initAuthOptions (C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\node_modules\\@salesforce\\core\\lib\\authInfo.js:509:53)",
        "warnings": [
            "The error message \"NoOrgFound\" has been deprecated and will be removed in v46 or later.  It will become \"NamedOrgNotFound\"."
    ]
}
```

I have used this command to validate

```sh
sfdx force:mdapi:deploy -c -d D:/GitCom/tmp/482c0eb0-272b-4fd2-ac27-65e706175218/main-deploy/force-app/main/default -u '00D18000000954Y!AQcAQEu9XXfRJP2hXd0lJX4Dp2CohWjDzXuvqrcNF' -w 5 --json
```

I am using Windows OS 10 and SFDX version

```
sfdx --version
sfdx-cli/7.28.7-7bceba6f24 win32-x64 node-v10.15.3
```

I am able to retrieve data from connected orgs, only deployment validation giving issue .

[image]

Comment: can you try the alias? SF-DEV/SFStage

Comment: how can I try alias?

Comment: add the `-u` flag along with the alias name

Comment: I know it has been a long time, but make sure you are setting the instance url for the org corresponding the accesstoken..
`sfdx force:config:set instanceUrl=https://na35.salesforce.com`
reference: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_auth_existing_access_token.htm

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation when you run `sfdx force:mdapi:deploy -h` the `-u` flag accepts

> username or alias for the target org; overrides default target

In your case, you appear to be trying to pass the OAuth access token direcly with this parameter, which is not how it works (unless there is some hidden secret way of using this parameter I'm not aware of). This would explain your "no org found" error.

So for you, based on the output from running `force:org:list`, you could either pass the alias or the username of whichever org you are trying to deploy to. I'll take a stab that you're aiming to deploy to staging, so you command would look like this:

```sh
sfdx force:mdapi:deploy -u SFStage -c -d D:/GitCom/tmp/482c0eb0-272b-4fd2-ac27-65e706175218/main-deploy/force-app/main/default -w 5 --json
```

Comment: using the access token is allowed based on this https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_auth_existing_access_token.htm

Comment: Good catch. I never use that and had completely forgotten it existed.